# meaning of the phrase "T plus" in context?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

That is from [Crash Course Astronomy](https://youtu.be/IGCVTSQw7WU). The sentence it was used in is at [5:41](https://youtu.be/IGCVTSQw7WU?t=5m41s). Here it goes:

> Then at T+20 minutes the universe cooled enough that fusion stopped.

I have looked it up in the internet, and what appeared is that it is an abbreviation meaning to think positive, but I cannot make head or tail of the sentence with this definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use *T minus [time]* to denote a countdown to the time an event occurs. You use *T plus [time]* to track the elapsed time since that event. This is language you might hear in a technical setting. Wikipedia gives the example of a [rocket launch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown):

> After a launch, most countdown clocks begin to show Mission Elapsed Time, which is typically shown as "T plus." The picture to the right shows "+ 00:00:07", approximately seven seconds after liftoff.
>   [image]

In the video, the man is explaining the events that occurred after the Big Bang. He called the time of the Big Bang "time zero". At *T plus twenty minutes* , he means twenty minutes after the Big Bang.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, T = time of some event

In the video 'T' is the instant the "Big Bang" began. So T+20minutes is 20 minutes after the initial start of the event.